# Check is Class is type of with inheritance check

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to check a python class based on their inheritance without instantiating it?

```
class Base(object):
    pass

class slaveA(Base):
    pass

class slaveB(Base):
    pass


def test(a):
    # that's not correct 
    return type(slaveA) == type(a)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(test(slaveB)) # should be False
    print(test(slaveA)) # should be True
    print(test(Base))  # should be True
```

Comment: Are you looking for [`issubclass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#issubclass)?

Comment: ah, great. Thank you. No idea how i could miss that one.